# How to change a column type from "Array" to "String" with Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, dataset

I have a dataset containing a column with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id_: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

where it can be seen that the second column, `payload`, contains lists of dictionaries as its entries. I would like to change the type of this column from `array` to `string`and I have tried the following code, as suggested by https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-convert-array-column-to-string-column/ :

```
df = df.withColumn("payload", concat_ws(",",col("payload")))
```

However, I am getting an unexpected error (see below). I think it is due to the fact that the lists contained in each column entry store dictionaries. Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

```
argument 2 requires (array<string> or string) type, however,`payload` is of array<map<string,string>> type.;
```

Many thanks,

Marioanzas

EDIT AFTER @SRINIVAS proposed solution: I get the following error.

```
Syntax Error.

File "unnamed_3", line 7
    df.withColumn("payload", F.expr(concat_ws(',',flatten(transform(payload,x -> transform(map_keys(x),y -> concat(y,x[y])))))))
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: ```F.expr("..")``` will take argument of type string , correct one - ```F.expr("concat_ws(',',flatten(transform(payload,x -> transform(map_keys(x),y -> concat(y,x[y])))))")```

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, thank you for your comment. I have tried what you suggested but I am still getting, when plotting the schema, that the payload is of type `array` and its elements are of type `map`. So it compiles for a long time (I have a large dataframe) but appears to do nothing:(

Answer (score 0):

Convert inside map key, value data to array of string then flatten data and pass result to `concat_ws` function.

Check below code.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- id_: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

```
df.show()

+----+----------------+
|id_ |payload         |
+----+----------------+
|id_a|[[a -> a value]]|
|id_b|[[b -> b value]]|
|id_c|[[c -> c value]]|
+----+----------------+
```

```
df
.withColumn(
    "payload",
    F.expr("concat_ws(',',flatten(transform(payload,x -> transform(map_keys(x),y -> concat(y,x[y])))))")
).show()

+----+--------+
|id_ |payload |
+----+--------+
|id_a|aa value|
|id_b|bb value|
|id_c|cc value|
+----+--------+
```

Spark Version - `2.4`

Comment: Hi Srinivas (@Srinivas ), many thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the code that you are suggesting but I get the an error which I am displaying at the end of the question body as an edit. Do you know how it can be solved? Maybe you can provide more details of the code?

Thanks